# What is the difference of types a->b and a->a1 in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to understand the following type signature in Haskell:

```
map (const (++)) :: [a] -> [[a1] -> [a1] -> [a1]]
```

I understand that map will apply the function (const (++)) on every element in the array [a]. Is it correct to assume that when (const (++)) is applied to an array-member, that the array-member will get ignored by const and the entire function will output an array full of (++)? e.g:

```
[(++), (++), (++), ... , (++)]
```

Since (++) has the type signature [a] -> [a] -> [a], why isn't the type signature of the entire function:

```
map (const (++)) :: [a] -> [[a] -> [a] -> [a]]
```

or

```
map (const (++)) :: [a] -> [[b] -> [b] -> [b]]
```

?

what is the special meaning of 'a1'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is of type `[a] -> [b]`

and as you correctly pointed out, `++` is of type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`

so the whole expression must be some sort of

`[a] -> [[b] -> [b] -> [b]]`

If you call `b`, `a1` instead is just notation.

Answer (score 1):

it is just a notation.

use of a1 instaed of say x is often used to make clear that the elements in the array of type [a] are the same as given to the function.

edit: was already answered before.